# Can a red wire be on the opposite side of a light switch from the live wire?

Tags: electrical

I replaced my 3-way light switch. They had the wires going directly into the switch, but the new switch only has the screw option. I have no ground wire for some reason. I wired my live wire (black) to my black screw and my Red wire is on the oppose side of the switch & my neutral wire is on the same side as the live wire. I originally had the red on the right side and white on the left but my outside sensor light wasn’t working so I switch the two and now it works. Is this safe?

Answer (score 1):

A switch does not need a neutral.  It sounds like the white is a traveler and you got it correct. It should be marked with some red or black tape or a marker.

Comment: Thank you! Glad to know cause I was confused at first because it was never marked as (traveler) so I thought it was a neutral. I saw some videos stating that you don’t need a neutral. Very helpful thanks

Comment: Or even better, mark _both_ travelers with _yellow_ tape to make it a bit more obvious.

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The switch positions can and do vary depening on manufacturers. You did right connecting the hot to the black screw as it's the common terminal. The other two screws are for the travelers and shouldn't make any difference in the positions. Your first wiring though should have worked by operating the other switch. Your switches should not need a neutral.

Comment: did you mean the switches should NOT need a neutral? It sounds to me like OP is talking about a traditional old-school switch. They mention a motion sensor, but I don't think it's part of the switch.

Comment: I thought the white wires was neutral at first but after answer this my question sounds like they used it as a traveler like you stated, jack. This is very old. Not sure when they added this switch for the sensor lights but it’s a old house.

Comment: Thanks jack. Yeah not sure why the first time didn’t work. It is working now but like I said just wanted to make sure this was safe. Knowing both the red and white wires is a traveler is great to know!

Comment: @izzy  Thanks, my bad